# export oid to file with postgres and php

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to export all files stored in my database (postgres) to a folder in my server and rename them.
What I have made:

```
// integer, oid, varchar
$sql =  pg_query($conn,"select id, image, extension from table");
while($sqlRow = pg_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $newimage= $sqlRow['id'].'.'.$sqlRow['extension']; 
    $path = '../_tmp/download/' . $newimage;
    pg_query($conn, "begin");
    $oid = pg_lo_create($conn);
    $handle = pg_lo_open($conn, $oid, "w");
    pg_lo_write($handle, "large object data");
    pg_lo_close($handle);
    pg_lo_export($conn, $oid, $path);   
    pg_query($conn, "commit");
}
```

With this code, I'm exporting and renaming the flies but when I try to open the files it gives me an error (invalid file), and the files are with 1kb and should be at least 400 kb each one.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @AlexR, when I try to open the file, it shows "Invalid File", it means is exporting wrongly, but If I try to read the file on browser using "encode(lo_get(image),'base64')", it works.

Comment: Perhaps you made a mistake reading the file (you didn't show that code).

Comment: I dont want to read the file, just export to folder on server. I wrote that above just to show that the file stored on databse is valid and working.